# Como impedir que un input de tipo file se vacié

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Tengo problemas con un input que se vacía**

Quisiera saber cómo puedo lograr que, al cargar un archivo, en un input donde tengo un
formulario, y hay campos obligatorios y yo procedo a cargar el archivo y doy clic en enviar el formulario y obviamente me resaltara los campos obligatorios pero el input donde cargue el archivo se vacía y yo quiero que este archivo permanezca cargado y *no se vacié el input.*

he intentado creándole un esta con el useState() pero no logro conseguirlo porque después el archivo no se carga en el input.

Estoy desarrollando en ReactJS con TypeScript.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola!, podrías poner el código que haces las validaciones o el submit?